# Spring boot Kotlin startup error: missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I generated project from start.spring.io.
My gradle project dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    kapt("org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.4.30.Final")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api")
}
```

Gradle jar configuration:

```
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.github.hadson172.findyourplace.FindYourPlaceApplicationKt"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree)
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
class FindYourPlaceApplication: SpringBootServletInitializer()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<FindYourPlaceApplication>(*args)
}
```

When i trying to deploy the application on dokku/heroku on startup I am getting error:

```
remote:        12:29:18.222 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
remote:         at com.github.hadson172.findyourplace.FindYourPlaceApplicationKt.main(FindYourPlaceApplication.kt:16)
remote:        Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:210)remote:         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
remote:         ... 8 common frames omitted
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is everything okay when you run it locally?

Do you check the [similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=missing%20ServletWebServerFactory%20bean)?

P.S. It is not an answer, but I have not enough points to leave comments :-)